# How to style an element when hovering another?

Tags: css

I know that this can be done when the objects are siblings of eachother or one is a child. But how could one achieve this effect when that is not the case?

Since this couldn't be done via the parent or sibling method (at least as far as I am aware), I turned to the internet but couldn't find any sensible solutions.

```html
<div class="x">
  <div class="y">
    <div class="z">
      <p class="hover-me"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="the-hover-should-effect-me"></div>
```

I expect the code to at the hover of `.hover-me` make me change `.the-hover-should-effect-me`, which as they aren't siblings or children I have yet to be to do.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with plain CSS, so you'll need to use JavaScript:

```
let hoverMe = document.querySelector('.hover-me');
hoverMe.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    // apply changes to .the-hover-should-effect-me
});
hoverMe.addEventListener('mouseout', () =>  {
    // revert changes to .the-hover-should-effect-me
});
```

If you have multiple pairings of `.hover-me` and `.the-hover-should-effect-me` then you can perform queries based on a common container that each pairing has.

Comment: No such `hover` Event.

Comment: I would use `mouseenter`, so there is not a bubbling issue.

Comment: @StackSlave Good point, fixed it to that.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a solution as of yet, that allows a child element of parent A, to affect parent B, via a pure CSS solution.

This can be achieved however with javsacript.

```
const hover = document.querySelector(".hover-me");
const hover_target = document.querySelector(".the-hover-should-effect-me");

hover.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    hover_target.textContent ="hi";
})
```